# Как сравнить значение аргумента командной строки со строковой константой?

Tags: c++, указатели, командная-строка

Почему в приведенном листинге argv[1] == "str" дает ложь даже если аргумент командной строки - "str"? 
Как сравнить значение аргумента командной строки со строковой константой?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  cout << argv[1] << " == " << "str" << endl
       << (argv[1] == "str");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что это разные типы данных. Обратите внимание, что тип аргумента командной строки это char*, т.е. массив символов с завершающим 0. Для сравнения надо использовать специальную функцию.

```
 #include <string.h>

    if(!strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
         some code;
    }
```

Либо преобразовать в std::string;

```
if (std::string(argv[i]) == "--help")
```

Comment: Или `using namespace std::literals;`, `argv[i] == "--help"sv`

Comment: Есть много вариантов)

Comment: Просто не вижу смысла в динамических аллокациях (`std::string`)

Comment: @int3 там нет динамической аллокации - просто создание временной переменной. В вашем варианте произойдет ровно тоже самое.

Comment: @Slava временный `std::string` (не берём в расчёт SSO) выделяет память в куче

Comment: @int3 возможно, но при использовании литерала ""s будет точно также создаваться временная переменная `argv[i]`

Comment: @Slava я использую литерал `sv`, прошу заметить. И в таком случае никаких аллокаций не произойдёт.

Comment: @int3 точно, прощелкал этот момент. Был неправ. Но стоит упоминать, что это требует C++17